# php post json text AND image in base64

Tags: php, json, post, base64

I try to send text and an image in base64 via the post method.

There is my code:

```
// $question is just text, and $photo_base64 is a photo (.png) encode in base64 with the javascript function btoa() 
function get_iframe($question, $token, $photo_base64){

    $url = 'http://www.squareoffs.com/api/v1/squareoffs?auth_token=' . $token;

    $data = array('question' => $question);
    $data['photo'] = 'data:image/png;base64,' . $photo_base64;

    $data = json_encode($data);

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $data
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    return json_decode($result);

}
```

But when a taste it (with correct argument), it does not work, the function return false instead of a json file. 
Does someone have a hint?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does not work... how. Taste has to be a bad translation.

Comment: You might want to post your JS code to generate the base64 aswell.

Comment: The javascript is very not important, I test the this function separatly.I test my function like that: 
get_iframe('my_question', 'D6yd2yfdMOifeSdddYC', 'iVBORw0KGgoA........AAANSUhEU');

And the encode photo in base64 is correct because I have reconstruct the phot from this string.